# Changes are not saved on Heroku after dyno restart

Tags: node.js, heroku, ghost-blog

I have installed ghost cms on Heroku using a Github repo. Whenever I am making some changes in my themes and uploading new themes the changes are unsaved after the Heroku dyno restart. How can I save changes permanently to my files in Heroku dyno after the restart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed Heroku dyno on each restart reverts it's state to state after application build. Removing data from Heroku Dyno is designed behaviour and I don't think you can do anything about it.

To make your data persist, you will have to use some outside storage. Basically, if you want to store files, you can use Amazon S3 bucket.

As you are using Ghost CMS you may be interested in [Ghost on Heroku](https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/snathjr/ghost-on-heroku)

If you want to know more about integrating Heroku with S3 bucket, you can check this [Heroku article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node)